# Disable WiFi when Ethernet connected on Windows 7 in a domain

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I have an issue with Windows 7 using 2 connections when connected to the domain. I have seen people say just turn off the WiFi but that's not a solution for domain users. In our environment we find that we are maxing out our DHCP server because Windows 7 insists on using both connections (LAN and wi-fi) which in turn takes up 2 IP addresses.

**Long story short:** Has anyone found a solution that will treat LAN connections like XP use to?

XP use to disable WiFi when it detected a LAN connection that way it only used 1 IP. I have seen this question come up a couple times on this site but the solutions seem directed to a single home user. Basically I would be interested in ways on how to do this through GPO, if possible.

I just want the domain PC's to use a single IP but I don't want to limit them should they undock and want to use the laptop in a meeting room for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are no wireless policies that I know of that can accomplish this, however:

There is a piece of software called [1NET](http://www.accessity.com.au/1Net.htm) that can disable WiFi on Ethernet connect that can be managed through GPO. I'm not affiliated with it, but I have used it and it works well.

> **Disconnect Wireless on Wired**
>
> 1NET can seamlessly disconnect from the corporate wireless/wifi network when the computer is connected by a wired connection. When the wired connection is disconnected, the corporate wireless/wifi network will be reconnected. 1NET works with all USB and traditional docks.

It can also be used to prevent network bridging while in a corporate environment.

### System Requirements

- Microsoft Windows 7 or Windows 8 (32bit or
  64bit)
- Microsoft Windows Domains
- Devices must be a member of a Windows
  Domain
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0
- Mobile broadband modems must be Windows 
  7/8 compatible and support the Windows
  WWAN Service

Comment: Thank you! :) I will certainly look into this more. In the world of growing wireless and mobile I guess I'm just surprised that we don't see more wireless policy options.  If I find anything else I will certainly share it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Moses, this is a feature request that's been made countless times to Microsoft.  They have yet to implement a GPO solution which does this.  While there are commercial programs to control the network adapters, it can be scripted as well.  If you're savvy and have the drive you can script it.  Here are some resources that will help:

[Solution from Spiceworks](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/278-disable-wireless-on-lan-script)

[Microsoft Scripting Guys - Powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/29/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-my-network-adapter.aspx)

Comment: I moderate for Spiceworks forums and I didn't even know about that script. Nice find!

Comment: Wow that's quite the read :) I certainly have more drive than time ;o)  I will let you know if this helped at all as I rather go with the DIY approach versus purchasing another app that I will need to manage. Thanks to both you and Moses you both have given me a good start. Cheers!